# ServerPlugins in Neo4j 2.0.0-M03: Where to create schema index

Tags: neo4j

I'm going to check out the new automatic indexing capabilities that come with Neo4j 2.0. They are described here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M03/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html

Now the automatic index must created at one point. The old way to get an index was just "indexManager.forNodes()" and the index was returned if existing, created if not. With automatic indexing, we just have to create the index once via "schema.indexFor()..." and then be done with it.

My question is, where do I best put the index creation? In the documentation example, they have a main method. But I'm working with a ServerPlugin. I'd like to create the indexes once at startup, if they do not already exist. But where can I do this? And how to I check whether the index already exists? I can get all IndexDefinition for a label. But since an IndexDefinition may depend on a label and on a arbitrary property, I would have to iterate through all IndexDefinitions for a specific label and check whether the one with the correct property does exist.

I could of course simply do what I just wrote, but it seems a bit cumbersome compared to the old index handling which would check automatically whether the requested index exists and create it, if not. So I'm wondering if I simply missed some key points with the handling of the new indices.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response from a Neo4j dev here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M03/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html

He proposes to create the automatic indexes in a neo4j start script, for instance. I also saw that someone already wished for unique indexes (would be a great feature!). That would simplify the index creation but in the end this is now a part of the database setup, it seems.